# Difference between dict.values and dict[key].values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the difference between `studentsDict.values()` and `studentsDict[key].values` in the following code?

```
studentsDict = {'Ayush': {'maths': 24, 'english': 19, 'hindi': 97, 'bio': 20, 'science': 0}, 'Pankaj': {'maths': 52, 'english': 76, 'hindi': 68, 'bio': 97, 'science': 66}, 'Raj': {'maths': 85, 'english': 79, 'hindi': 51, 'bio': 36, 'science': 75}, 'iC5z4DK': {'maths': 24, 'english': 92, 'hindi': 31, 'bio': 29, 'science': 91}, 'Zf1WSV6': {'maths': 81, 'english': 58, 'hindi': 85, 'bio': 31, 'science': 7}}

for key in studentsDict.keys():
    for marks in studentsDict[key].values():
        if marks < 33:
            print(key, "FAILED")
            break
```

Comment: studentsDict is a dictionary of dictionaries. studentsDict.keys() will reveal Ayush, Pankaj etc. The studentsDict[key].values() will reveal 24, 19 etc (for Ayush)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please format your code by using ' \` ' eg. `code`.

Answer (score 0):

`studentsDict.keys()` gives you each of the keys in the outer dict: "Ayush", "Pankaj", "Raj", "iC5z4DK" and "Zf1WSV6".

`studentsDict[key].values()` gives you the values for the entry in studentsDict corresponding to `key`. For example, if `key` is "Ayush", you would get 24, 19, 97, 20, and 0.